# hide div until all background images have loaded

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to wait until all background images have loaded before some code is executed?  I know this works for one image but how can I adapt it for various images?

```
var firstBackgroundImage = new Image();         
                firstBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
                        $('#main-slider').animate({opacity:1}),600;

            }; 
            firstBackgroundImage.src = "http://www.domain.com/img/iphone.png";
```

HTML

```
 <div id="main-slider"></div>
```

CSS

```
#main-slider{
   opacity:0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: All images on the page or a certain amount?

Comment: just a few specific background images in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // this code gets executed when all content of the page (including images) is loaded 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for complete page. I mean a loading image will be displayed hiding your main div until every component is being loaded completely..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            // calculate height
            var screen_ht = jQuery(window).height();
            var preloader_ht = 5;
            var padding = (screen_ht / 5) - preloader_ht;
            jQuery("#preloader").css("padding-top", padding + "px");


            // loading animation using script 

            function anim() {
                jQuery("#preloader_image").animate({ left: '1px' }, 2000,
                function () {
                    jQuery("#preloader_image"), animate({ left: '1px' }, 2000);
                }
                );
            }
            //anim();
        });
    function hide_preloader() {
    // To apply Fade Out Effect to the Preloader 
    jQuery("#preloader").fadeOut(1000);
    }
    </script>
<style>
    #preloader {background: #1c1c1c;position:fixed;left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;color:#fff;z-index: 100000000;}
    #preloader div {width:228px;height:240px;margin:auto;padding:10px 0;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;}
    #preloader_image {width:228px;height:240px;position: relative;left:0px;top:-10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body id="home" onload="hide_preloader()">
    <div id="preloader">
        <div>
            <div id="preloader_image">
                <img src="loading.gif" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 35%;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: how does that work exactly? An especially for various background images? Could the code I used in the OP not be adapted?